# Time stamp for saving file or folder?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a simpler way to do a time stamp for saving a file/creating a directory as a date time stamp ?
only using standard library (not boost). Is there a faster way to do it ?

This is my current code

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
tm utc_tm = *gmtime(&tt);   
oname.str("");
oname << (utc_tm.tm_year + 1900) << '-' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (utc_tm.tm_mon + 1) << '-' << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << utc_tm.tm_mday << "  " << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2)<< utc_tm.tm_hour <<':' <<  std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << utc_tm.tm_min <<':' <<  std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << utc_tm.tm_sec;
ts = oname.str();
```

Comment: Using `sprintf()` or similar would probably be one way to simplify it.

Comment: "faster"? Probably not measurable if you actually use it to create/open a file. You could of course use `strftime` to format some sort of time-value.

Comment: I'm using it to save 2 jpeg result files via opencv(which is a lot slower). When I need ms precision switch to using duration with high_precision clock eg high_resolution_clock::time_point start = high_resolution_clock::now(); milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds> (high_resolution_clock::now() - start);

Comment: So measure the time first, then convert to filename and open files - if you don't do it that way, time will be affected by conversion (small amount) and file-opening (large amount).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a less tortuous way:

```
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

std::string get_timestamp()
{
    auto now = std::time(nullptr);
    char buf[sizeof("YYYY-MM-DD  HH:MM:SS")];
    return std::string(buf,buf + 
        std::strftime(buf,sizeof(buf),"%F  %T",std::gmtime(&now)));
}
```

It is very probably also faster, because it is less tortuous, but that is
also very probably immaterial in a setting where disc I/O is in play.

This gives you the same timestamps as your own code, e.g.

```
2015-03-28  10:48:45
```

See [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) and 
[`std::strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) to 
understand how the desired formatting is achieved and note that `std::strftime`
returns the length of the string it has composed, excluding its nul-terminator.

This code is standard, but if you are working with MS VC++ 2013 or later then
you could also consider the use of [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time),
as in:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

std::string get_timestamp()
{
    auto now = std::time(nullptr);
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << std::put_time(std::gmtime(&now),"%F  %T");
    return os.str();
}
```

which is simpler still. (I have not tested that.) `std::put_time` however 
is unsupported by gcc as of 4.9.

Seemingly you want your timestamps formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD  HH:MM:SS`. If they
are to be used in filenames, it would be more prudent to keep them free of spaces:
perhaps `YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS`.

Comment: Thanks, mostly working on linux with gcc 4.8 and 4.9.